# Crear icono Entidad Acción Fontawesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

estoy usando **font-awesome** y sus iconos deseo crear algo así:

[image: awe]

tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <i class="fa fa-cube fa-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-top: 14px; margin-left:-1px;"></i>
```

el resultado obtenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como puedo alinearlo como la primera imagen y un border-radius, quiza alguna sugerencia.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando [`Stacked icons`](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#stacked), podrías hacerlo así:

```css
.fa {
  color: #706f6f;
}
.fa-stack-rounded {
  border: 6px solid #706f6f;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(25%, 25%) scale(0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
  <i class="fa fa-cube fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-stack-rounded"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: genial gracias.!!